# Mapping values from foreign keys in table

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate for my project and what i'm essentially trying to do is figure out how to auto-map the values with foreign keys from my table in the database to a data object.

For example, I have a users table with the following columns

```
id - INT
username - VARCHAR
password - VARCHAR
email - VARCHAR
firstName - VARCHAR
lastName - VARCHAR
```

This is fairly straightforward to map as there are no foreign keys involved. The code I have is:

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            q.setString(0, username);
            q.setString(1, password);
            q.addEntity(User.class);

            List<User> users = q.list()
```

Now supposing I add some foreign keys to my user table such as

```
userlevel_id - INT
department_id - INT
```

Which reference the user level a user belongs to and the department. How do I get hibernate to map the user level name from the userlevel table and the department name from the department table? It wont be of much use if I just store the id's in the User data object as I will need to display the values to my views later on. Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use an eagerly loaded `@ManyToOne` mapping on your `User` object. Make an object to represent both your `Department`and your `UserLevel` and add them as fields into your `User` object. The reason that you should have this mapping as eagerly loaded is that there is never a situation where you don't want to load a `User` without their `Department` or `UserLevel`. Hibernate will automatically map your `User` object to the appropriate `Department` and `UserLevel`.

If you want too, you can make the relationship [bi-directional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional) so you can get all users in a department by selecting a department. Anything you can do in SQL you can map using Hibernate.

Have a read of the documentation and see if that helps.